# Python regex to find string ending in double new line without a period

Tags: python, regex

I have a long string like this:

```
Page Content

Director, Research Center.

Director of Research, Professor

Researcher
```

Lines end in a double newline. Some contain period in the end, some don't. I want each that had a double newline one to contain a single period and a single new line, like this:

```
Page Content.
Director, Research Center.
Director of Research, Professor.
Researcher.
```

There are also lines which end with a period and a single newline and they should stay the way they are. What I've tried:

```
re.sub('(?!\.)\n\n', '.\n', text)
```

What I'm trying to do is a negative on the period followed by two newlines, or find every single double new line that doesn't have a period right before and replace it with a period and a single newline.

I've tried some other variations, but I always end up with either double period or no changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookbehind instead to assert what is on the left is not a dot. Escape the dot `\.` to match it literally.

```
(?<!\.)\n\n
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lJF67H/1)

Or to match an optional `\r` you could use a quantifier to repeat a non capturing group:

```
(?<!\.)(?:\r?\n){2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/raZldv/1)

Comment: Negative lookbehind is exactly what I needed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant, but obviously working:

```
text = text.replace('\.\n\n', '\n\n').replace('\n\n', '.\n')
```

If you insist on using `re.sub`:

```
text = re.sub('([^.])\.?\n\n', r'\1.\n', text)
```

This is downright ugly, but works too.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using something similar for now. Gonna leave question open for a while, maybe I'll get a proper regex answer

Comment: I feel like the negative lookbehind is cleaner, but thanks your your input anyway!